# macOS Mojave download problem from Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, mojave

Anyone has any solution for macOS Mojave download problem? When downloading the installer app from the Mac App Store, the download resumes fine, but just when it's about to complete, it disappears, and the download button shows **Download** again. I've tried it 5-6 times, and not being able to download the installer successfully.

I am currently running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Is your Mac enrolled in any management system such as Jamf Pro?  Are you running any 3rd-party security software such as Malwarebytes?  Have you tried using a different user account to download Mojave, or a different Internet connection?  What happens if you restart into Safe Boot (hold down Shift) and retry this download?

Comment: Yes yes it worked, I restated into safe boot and it started installing the new OS. thanks @da4

Comment: Please post the answer with all the steps of problem resolution.